# É correto escrever CSS com Javascript?

Tags: css, vue.js

Vejo um enfoque em frameworks javascript, para escrever o css diretamente em javascript, exemplo...

```js
new Vue({
  el : "#style",
  data : {
    ctn : {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      flexDirection: "column",
      height: "100vh",
    },
    header : {
      fontSize: "20pt",
      color: "blue",
    },
    article : {
      fontSize: "13pt",
      color: "green",
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="style" :style="ctn">

  <header :style="header">Hello world!</header>
  
  <article :style="article">StackOverflow</article>

</div>
```

Isso facilita muito, pois permite o uso de variáveis e funções, mas para um projeto extenso, essa prática implicaria em algum problema?

**Edit**

Recentemente encontrei esse artigo [Paz no css (Medium)](https://medium.com/@didoo/let-there-be-peace-on-css-8b26829f1be0)

[Artigo original](http://www.didoo.net/2017/10/let-there-be-peace-on-css/)

E percebi que esse debate está acontecendo veemente na internet (Como sempre o Brasil não está muito por dentro).

Comment: Depende da sua definição de problema. Se você vai ganhar a mesma coisa independente do esforço de manutenção, isso é um grande problema. Mas se você ganha por hora ou por linha de código, isso aí é garantia de estabilidade por um tempo. O trabalho que você vai ter para manter o design visual do seu site só vai aumentar cada vez mais.

Comment: Eu nunca vi nenhuma documentação oficial do Vue recomendar isso. Inclusive eles têm uma solução para "aproximar" o CSS do código JS, deixando os dois no mesmo arquivo: os [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Comment: também nunca vi, me referi a um enfoque que eu percebi, tanto é que existem várias libs hoje para esse tipo de técnica http://cssinjs.org/?v=v9.0.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A ideia de VueJS (creio que seja a mesma do AngularJS) em usar definição de atributos CSS diretamente na TAG dinamicamente tem como objetivo fazer pequenas manipulações no DOM.

Eu particularmente não utilizaria da maneira que você fez, pois é desnecessário.

Considere que os atributos que você definiu aí são praticamente estáticos. Você poderia perfeitamente usar uma tag `style`, ou `link` para incluir uma folha de estilo externa.

Eu creio que a ideia por trás da definição de estilos dinamicamente
é você pode usar isso para fazer alteração de atributos estrategicamente, como no caso de ocultar um botão de compras caso não tenha nenhum produto selecionado:

```
 <button :style="{visibility: produtos_do_carrinho.length == 0 ? 'hidden' :  'visible'">
       Comprar
 </button>
```

Observe que além de definir através de um objeto o valor de `:style`, você também poderá usar [expressões condicionais](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/conditional-style-in-vue-component/17020/2).

É importante lembrar que, se a expressão da propriedade específica for avaliada como `false`, este mesmo será removido.

Exemplo:

```
<div :style="{color: false, display: flexibilizar == true ? 'block' : 'flex' }"></div>

<!-- resultado -->
<div style="display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: Aquele que negativou a resposta podia apontar o erro na resposta. É válido lembrar que o objetivo do voto é de avaliar se a pergunta/resposta está certa ou errada, e não se eu gostei ou não da pessoa que respondeu.

Comment: concordo contigo, já mudei minha opinião para esse tipo de técnica

Comment: @sannyas Pense assim pra facilitar: o objetivo de definir o css através de `:style` em VUEJS é a mesma coisa de você definir o css através de `$(elemento).css({...})` do jQuery! Você não escreveria todo seu CSS no jQuery, porque é inviável e não faz sentido.

Comment: Faz todo sentido baseado dentro de um "ecossistema" especifico esperando certos tipos de comportamentos dinâmicos, como em Angular ou Vue. Por enfeite ou achar que "é legal" realmente não faz sentido e muito menos será proveitoso, será apenas retrabalho, para quem escreve o código tanto para o navegador fazer o "parse"... +1

Answer (score 4):

Isso pode impactar muito no desenvolvimento do layout, a não ser que você queira apenas trabalhar com o visual estático do framework, aí que vem o problema em customizar as linhas de código no `js` para se ter o visual esperado, uma vez que a construção do layout dentro do javascript será demasiadamente grande.

Você pode atribuir um `style` ou chamar uma animação do `css` pelo javascript, deixando assim o javascript assumir a renderização de forma muito dinâmica, e se tiver usando `node.js` ou `ajax` para requisição verá que é muito comum manipular atributos e classes do css para renderizar uma tabela, uma div.

Outro dado importante a analisar é o carregamento do layout que por sua vez carrega todo `css` no `onload do body` e o `javascript` ao final do body, por questão de carga no servidor, poi o `js` tende a ser mais pesado que o `js` e pode demorar na montagem do site ou sistema, em exemplo de estrutura html se baseia nisso:

```
<html>
<head>
<link css >// carrega no inicio para deixar o layout pronto
</head>
<body>
<p>... conteúdo</p>
<script src="link css">//carrega no fim para não impactar no load da página
</body>
</html>
```

Isso para um desenvolvedor de `frontend` não é aconselhavel e agencias de publicidade que mudam constantemente os Layouts, não irão partir para está prática neste momento.

tudo vai depender da forma de programar a da carga de trabalho que será exigida na manutenção do layout.

Answer (score 4):

Eu costume dizer que "se é possível, tem algum uso", mas cara SEMPRE que for possível aplicar o conceito de **responsabilidade** (cada um cuida do que é seu), o faça. Tendo em vista que o JS vem depois do CSS na "fila" do DOM sua aplicação terá um grande "*nada*" aparecendo para o usuário antes do seu JS ser carregado.

Já notou que o no load do Facebook, ou de outras plataformas (principalmente as plataformas da Google), aparecem um retângulos cinzas para o lugar dos textos, retângulos quadrados para onde vai ficar a foto, e assim por diante? Esse é o *Wireframe* da pagina em css, quando isso aparece que dizer que o JS ainda não carregou, então ele não deixa o usuário com uma tela branca sem saber se está acontecendo algo ou não.

**CONCLUSÃO**
Só use quando não tiver mais nenhum jeito de usar CSS inline, internal, ou external, por conta de responsabilidade (ajustar o layout não é trabalho dele, o JS *dinamiza* o layout).

Comment: Interessante esse conceito de responsabilidade, as vezes nos acostumamos demais com certa linguagem e queremos sair usando para tudo kk.

Comment: Sim vdd, hahaha